# configuring Teamcity for CVS branch and tag checkout

Tags: tags, branch, teamcity, cvs

I am trying to integrate Teamcity 8.x with cvs. While I was able to successfully integrate it while checking out head revisions, Whenever I tried checking out from a branch or from a revision tag, the build agent does not seem to check out for branches and tags. I am selecting the radio button checkout from branch and checkout from tag. Is this a bug with the latest teamcity. I would be extremely grateful if someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Did you try checking out on the server? Does that work?